# Why cannot parse stylesheet simple xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xsl fragment that shows error message in XML Copy Editor when I transform using F8. It shows

> Cannot transform: Cannot parse stylesheet

```
    <xsl:value-of select="$iterator"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$step"/> 
    <xsl:when test="$step = $iterator">
      equal
    </xsl:when>
```

The problem is with the `xsl:when`. When I remove that element, the error message is gone and the stylesheet works without problems.

What is wrong with this element?

Comment: Please always post a **complete** - even if minimal - example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is wrong with this element?

I am only guessing here, because you're not showing us a reproducible example, but `xsl:when` must be a child of `xsl:choose`.

OTOH, `xsl:value-of` must **not** be a child of `xsl:choose` - so the error is either here or there.

Comment: All true (+1) and we might further guess that OP may want `xsl:if` here instead of `xsl:when`.